# How to use Joined table in django queryset

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

i was join two table and i want to get field in joined model class

```
school_name_list = Students.objects.select_related('School').values('school_name')
```

but this code raise

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'school_name' into field``
```

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If `School` is foreign key attribute in `Students` model, then use `School__school_name` in values.

```
students = Students.objects.values('School__school_name')
```

If you are accessing only a particular field like `School__school_name` only (using `values`), there is no need to add `select_related` because fields that are in `values` will be fetched.

Comment: values('School__school_name') is not working but values('school__school_name') is working thx

Comment: Yes. That's what I mentioned. Most probably `School` will be your model and `school` is your foreign key attribute.